# Rails 4, Paperclip and polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have 2 models: News and Uploadedfile

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :uploadedfiles, as: :parent
    attr_accessible :title, :content, :author
end

class Uploadedfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
    has_attached_file :url
    attr_accessible :url_file_name, :url_content_type, :url_file_size, :url_updated_at
end
```

And form:

```
<%= form_for(@news) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">

        <%= f.fields_for :uploadedfile, f.uploadedfile.new do |uf| %>
            <%= uf.label :url %><br>
            <%= uf.file_field :url %>
        <% end %>

    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When i'm submitting form, my table `uploadedfile` is not changed

where is the problem? thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have nested arribute `:uploadedfiles`

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :uploadedfiles, as: :parent
    attr_accessible :title, :content, :author, :uploadedfiles_attributes
    accept_nested_attributes_for :uploadedfiles
end
```

And in form :
change:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :uploadedfile, f.uploadedfile.new do |uf| %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :uploadedfiles, Uploadedfile.new do |uf| %>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I've just added :uploadedfiles_attributes to attr_accessible in news model and now row is added in the sql-table. But uploadedfiles fields are empty

Comment: Thank you! I've just rename `:url` to `:file` and added string `attr_accessible :file` to `uploadedfiles` model.
It works!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need polymorphic association here. Here is a more readable way of doing this:

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :uploadedfiles
    attr_accessible :title, :content, :author
    accept_nested_attributes_for :uploadedfiles
end

class Uploadedfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :news
    has_attached_file :url
    attr_accessible :url_file_name, :url_content_type, :url_file_size, :url_updated_at
end
```

*note that I've added **accept_nested_attributes_for**

And the form:

```
<%= form_for(@news) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">

        <%= f.fields_for :uploadedfiles do |uf| %>
            <%= uf.label :url %><br>
            <%= uf.file_field :url %>
        <% end %>

    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you! Now ruby is building helper in form, but sql-table `uploadedfile` not changed :c Maybe I should to add some code to controller?

Comment: Since you are using Rails 4 you'll need to permit these parameters. There should be sth like params.require(:news).permit(:name....). You should add the uploadedfiles fields. Like this:
params.require(:news).permit(:name, :whatever, ..., :uploadedfiles_attributes => [:url])

Comment: I've already permitted these parameters:
params.require(:news).permit(:title, :content, :author, :uploadedfiles_attributes => [:url])

Comment: I do not know how to do it in ruby

Comment: In your controller:
puts params.inspect

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "news"=>{"title"=>"test",
 "content"=>"test",
 "author"=>"test",
 "uploadedfiles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"url"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb64e424 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140325-7654-180yewf>,
 @original_filename="image.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"news[uploadedfiles_attributes][0][url]\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}},
 "commit"=>"Create News"}

Comment: Seems fine to me. Maybe it's something with the controller.

Comment: I've just added `:uploadedfiles_attributes` to `attr_accessible` in news model and now row is added in the sql-table. But uploadedfiles fields are empty