# How to save tag with many to many relationship in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to create a video with many-to-many tags. So, each tag would be each row in `Tag` table. I'm not sure I have to do it myself or Rails has some magic that could do that?

Here's my model.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :video_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :video_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class VideoTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Here's my form

```
<%= form_for(@video, html: { class: "directUpload" }, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :path %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :path%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's my `Controller`

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @videos = Video.where(user_id: params[:user_id])

  end

  def new
        @video = Video.new
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public_read)
  end


  def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    @video.user_id = 1
    if @video.save
        redirect_to @video
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def video_params
        params.require(:video).permit(:title, :path, :tags)
  end

end
```

But then I got this error which I thought I must have missed something. I just want to have tag separated by space.

> ```
> Started POST "/videos" for ::1 at 2015-04-07 00:21:11 -0400
> Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"authenticity_token",
> ```
>
> "video"=>{"title"=>"asdfasdf",
>   "path"=>"//s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/token/57203191c21df0cacf98f3fa9340f4.mp4",
>   "tags"=>"test "}, "commit"=>"Create Video"}
>       Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
>
> ```
> NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "test ":String):
>   app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:14:in `create'
> ```

Comment: Can you post your server log when you're trying to create a video from UI?

Comment: I don't see `each` in line number 14 in videos_controller. Is there something you've not posted here in your question?

Comment: I have a feeling that you messed up your association.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed I believe so. I'm new to RoR. What I want is that User has many videos and a video has many tags which one tag belongs to many videos.

Comment: @toy, I have given an answer suggesting you the association. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My following answer will help you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611372/rails-4-paperclip-and-polymorphic-association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611372/rails-4-paperclip-and-polymorphic-association/22614020#22614020)

you can use `accept_nested_attributes_for` and,

```
 <%= f.fields_for :tags, @_your_tags do |t| %>
```

instead of

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :tags %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :tags %>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this mean I'd have multiple text fields?

Comment: Yes, that have multiple text fields. But tags input with some  jQuery will help you for single text field for tagging instead of `f.fields_for`. Only parameter needs to be like, `{ videos => { tags => ['a', 'b'] } }`

Answer (score 1):

Your association would be like this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :video_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :video_tags
end

class VideoTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_tags
  has_many :videos, through :video_tags
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this wiki](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms) pretty helpful. And yes rails has a special way to handle this. These are called nested models or you can also user nested_form gem